# Change programmatically color of title bar of dialog, color is not pre-defined. Android

Tags: java, android

How do I set the color of a an android app's dialog's title bar (currently blue, seen in snapshot) at runtime i.e. the color is received inside the java code at runtime?

[image: Snapshot of a full-screen dialog]

Comment: @James color is not predefined, as I said, so I cannot specify any color in XML

Comment: How are you creating the dialog? Your issue is not clear enough. please add more details. If you just want to know `how to set the color of a dialog pragmatically` then this question is a duplicate like @James said.

Comment: This is not duplicate. The word "Dialog" has fooled anyone, this has nothing to do with `android.app.Dialog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set title color of dialog:

```
m_dialog = new Dialog(this); // your dialog
m_dialog.getWindow().setTitleColor(R.color.pink_background);
```

Or you can even set drawable:

```
m_dailog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

**EDIT**
According to your comment, if you don't have color pre-defined than you need to do something like this:

Example:

```
m_tvMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#AA0000"));
```

Comment: resource id demands a color to be PRE-DEFINED in XML which I cannot, because the color is NOT PRE-DEFINED.

Comment: pl check my edited answer..

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
final Dialog dailog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dailog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dailogbox);
```

put dailogbox.xml in your resource/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:centerColor="#660D1E4A"
        android:endColor="#66011444"
        android:startColor="#66505E7F"
        android:type="linear"
         />

    <stroke
        android:dashGap="0dp"
        android:dashWidth="0dp"
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ffffffff" />

</shape>
```

Comment: in this, where do I get the functionality of passing a color (coming from another source hence it is unknown beforehand) at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for changing color of your dialog programatically

```
    dialog = new Dialog(this); // your dialog
    dialog.getWindow().setTitleColor(R.color.blue_background);
```